# Applying CMake setup for children projects

Tags: c++, c, cmake, include, glfw

I have a project directory setup like this:

```
3rdparty 
    |--glfw
test
   |--3rdparty
      |--googletest
   |--CMakeLists.txt (Test project CMakeLists)
CMakeLists.txt (Main project CMakeLists)
```

In the main project in setting up the external dependencies:

```
add_subdirectory(3rdparty/glfw)
target_link_libraries(Main glfw)
```

What is the best way to apply all dependencies also for the Test project? Am I supposed to redo all the dependency code also in child CMakeLists.txt? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is `link_libraries` command, which links with the given library all targets which will be created after the command call. Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you have a test project, you have to link your test executables to the rest of the code. By doing that using CMake, you should automatically get transitive dependencies. However, to do that you need the CMake target based API.

```
add_executable(Main ... your cpp files ...)
add_library(YourLib ... your cpp files ...)

add_subdirectory(3rdparty/glfw) # or find_package(glfw)

# link YourLibs to glfw
target_link_libraries(YourLibs PUBLIC glfw)

# link Main to YourLibs and its public dependencies
target_link_libraries(Main PUBLIC YourLibs)
```

Then in your test cmake file, link to the same target as your exe to gain access for your own function, include directories and libraries:

```
add_executable(Test cppfile.cpp)
add_test(Test)
target_link_libraries(Test PRIVATE YourLibs gtest)
```